# How to change behaviour of linux command acoding to user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to write a script that when I open a suppose 'file.txt' with cat>file.txt  then my script get activate on seeing cat command in execution and filename with .txt extension and append date at end of file and then open. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at `libinotify`

Comment: Don't do that(it will break things). What is the end goal?

Comment: I can give you an exxample ,every time we open a new terminal we can customize it like we can show date,or any pattern at the top of a new terminal . We can make all these  changes in .bashrc file . so like that i want to know can we make to the command  also?